# Multi Threading OpenCV camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to run two 60fps cameras in parallel, however, I am finding it difficult to manage parallel threads. Are there any open source codes for this job.
Note: I do not wish to use boost libraries

Comment: What about [standard C++ threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)?

Comment: I am trying std::thread option butI find it difficult to manage all mutex and condition variables. Therefore I was looking for library optioins.

Comment: You can also use Qt's QThread http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html